# Docker - Error establishing a database connection

Tags: wordpress, docker, npm, docker-compose

Im on Mac 14.2.1 and Docker 4.27.2. Just today an error has started when running `npm run wp-env start` the container is created and is running but an error is displayed stating that there is an issue with the database connection.

```
➜  TEST npm run wp-env start

> @ wp-env /Users/ciaran/Projects/TEST
> wp-env "start"

⚠ Warning: could not find a .wp-env.json configuration file and could not determine if '/Users/ciaran/Projects/TEST' is a WordPress installation, a plugin, or a theme.
✖ Error while running docker compose command.
 Container 31ccb2fb25f5a8b628d4a487d8d7a7d7-tests-mysql-1  Running
 Container 31ccb2fb25f5a8b628d4a487d8d7a7d7-tests-wordpress-1  Running
Error: Error establishing a database connection. This either means that the username and password information in your `wp-config.php` file is incorrect or that contact with the database server at `tests-mysql` could not be established. This could mean your host’s database server is down.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ wp-env: `wp-env "start"`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the @ wp-env script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/ciaran/.npm/_logs/2024-02-21T16_45_59_997Z-debug.log
```

log

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   '/Users/ciaran/.nvm/versions/node/v14.21.3/bin/node',
1 verbose cli   '/Users/ciaran/.nvm/versions/node/v14.21.3/bin/npm',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'wp-env',
1 verbose cli   'start'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.18
3 info using node@v14.21.3
4 verbose run-script [ 'prewp-env', 'wp-env', 'postwp-env' ]
5 info lifecycle @~prewp-env: @
6 info lifecycle @~wp-env: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~wp-env: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~wp-env: PATH: /Users/ciaran/.nvm/versions/node/v14.21.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/Users/ciaran/Projects/TEST/node_modules/.bin:/Users/ciaran/.nvm/versions/node/v14.21.3/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/ciaran/.nvm/versions/node/v14.21.3/bin:/opt/homebrew/bin:/opt/homebrew/sbin
9 verbose lifecycle @~wp-env: CWD: /Users/ciaran/Projects/TEST
10 silly lifecycle @~wp-env: Args: [ '-c', 'wp-env "start"' ]
11 silly lifecycle @~wp-env: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~wp-env: Failed to exec wp-env script
13 verbose stack Error: @ wp-env: `wp-env "start"`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/Users/ciaran/.nvm/versions/node/v14.21.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:400:28)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/Users/ciaran/.nvm/versions/node/v14.21.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:400:28)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1088:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:296:5)
14 verbose pkgid @
15 verbose cwd /Users/ciaran/Projects/TEST
16 verbose Darwin 23.2.0
17 verbose argv "/Users/ciaran/.nvm/versions/node/v14.21.3/bin/node" "/Users/ciaran/.nvm/versions/node/v14.21.3/bin/npm" "run" "wp-env" "start"
18 verbose node v14.21.3
19 verbose npm  v6.14.18
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error @ wp-env: `wp-env "start"`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the @ wp-env script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

any help on this would be great.

I've nuked docker, NVM and Node and reinstalled to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem today too. Apparently, there's something wrong with MariaDB. Here is what I did to fix it on my Mac:

1. Open the docker container file (for me it was located at /(myusername)/.wp-env/(container_name)

Your container name in this case will be: `31ccb2fb25f5a8b628d4a487d8d7a7d7`

**Note:** You will need to do cmd + shift + . to see the .wp-env file because it is hidden

2. Open the `docker-compose.yml` file in a code editor.
3. Underneath `image: mariadb`, create a new line and enter: `command: --character-set-server=utf8mb4 --collation-server=utf8mb4_bin`

I had to enter this 2 times, so check if `image: mariadb` appears more than once

4. Save the `docker-compose.yml` file and delete everything else in the folder
5. Open terminal and navigate to `/(username)/.wp-env/(container_name)` using the `cd` command
6. Enter `docker compose up -d` to start Wordpress

Do not use `wp-env` start because it will overwrite your `docker-compose.yml` file.

Your Wordpress site should be working now when you visit localhost:8888. (You may have to setup the site manually).

If you need more info, I got this from here: https://github.com/MariaDB/mariadb-docker/issues/560